# Pseudo-element transition with IE11

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-transforms, pseudo-element

I try to use some creative link effets (found on https://tympanus.net/Development/CreativeLinkEffects/ ) but 
unfortunately the 3D transition effect doesn't work with IE11.

Here is a copenden test with these links : http://codepen.io/koban/pen/NdXbrz 
Seems like the `span::before` doesn't show himself for some reason...

Have you any idea of how to fix this bug?

Comment: Have you tried using `-ms-` prefixes? I'm not on a PC so can't test it.

Comment: @allnodcoms I have used the "autoprefixer" and "prefixfree" options in codepen but it didn't change anything

Comment: From MDN:
>Mixing 3D and 2D transform functions, such as -ms-transform:rotate(10deg) translateZ(0);, will prevent the entire property from being applied.
Try removing the translate and see if it works. It would narrow the search down.

Comment: @allnodcoms I removed the translate but it didn't work better :/

Comment: preserve-3d is not supported by IE